# How can I set "allow_dynamic_fields" on a per collection basis in Mongoid?

Tags: mongoid

Mongoid only seems to have an app wide `Mongoid.allow_dynamic_fields` setting. But I want every collection to decide whether it wants dynamic fields or not. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you already find a solution for your problem? Because I have the same at the moment :).

Comment: Nah buddy .. I did not. I basically allowed it for all and controlled the params in the controller myself.

Comment: Apparently coming in Mongoid 4.0: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2048

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in mongoid 3.x yet even though there is a pull request already for it, https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/2563. This will be released on mongoid 4.0. However if you really need that feature you could checkout those 2 commits in a local folder or in a fork , an use it.